# Layout setmargins not working on large screens

Tags: android

Here is my problem:

Im creating radiogroups with 4 imagebuttons as radiobuttons. It works in all screen sizes, but in large screens the setmargin is ignored. All four buttons touches the buttons beside them.

The setmargin works fine in normal screen sizes.

Here is the code:

```
ImageButton botaoSim = criaImageButton(++id, R.drawable.ic_like_grey, rootView.getContext());
ImageButton botaoNao = criaImageButton(++id, R.drawable.ic_dislike_grey, rootView.getContext());
ImageButton botaoAvariado = criaImageButton(++id, R.drawable.ic_taca_quebrada, rootView.getContext());
ImageButton botaoNaoSeAplica = criaImageButton(++id, R.drawable.ic_na, rootView.getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
radioGroup.addView(botaoSim, layoutParams);
radioGroup.addView(botaoNao, layoutParams);
radioGroup.addView(botaoAvariado, layoutParams);
radioGroup.addView(botaoNaoSeAplica, layoutParams);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ToggleListener);
```

I've tried with padding, ViewGroup.LayoutParams, RelativeLayout.layoutParams, layoutParams.rightMargin, view.requestLayout() but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

If you are having the same problem: spaces between radioButtons are ignored on large screens.

You can use an invisible custom divider, create a **drawable**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
        <size android:width="10dip" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
```

then use the divider in your radioGroup like this:

```
    radioGroup.setDividerDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vertical_divider));
    radioGroup.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
```